# pandas: change strange dictionary type of data into dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I am dealing with predictions results take a strange form, and I am not finding a way to transform it into something actionable aka a dataframe.

I am heard of itertools but it does not seem to make the trick for me, unless I am using it wrong.

here is what I tried doing:

```
forecast = {}
def holts(i):
    fit1 = ExponentialSmoothing(new_df.iloc[:,i], trend=True).fit()
    prediction_interval = fit1.get_forecast(steps=12).summary_frame(alpha=0.10) #make predictions

    df = pd.DataFrame(prediction_interval).reset_index()#put in dataframe
   
   

    forecast[i] = df # append results to dictionary
    print(forecast)
    return forecast
```

this returns a dictionary like that:

```
{0: 100121      index      mean   mean_se  mean_ci_lower  mean_ci_upper
0      2020-07-31 -1.422683  7.346106     -13.505952      10.660585
1      2020-08-31 -1.875716  7.346106     -13.958985      10.207552
2      2020-09-30 -2.328749  7.346106     -14.412019       9.754520, 
1: 100140      index       mean     mean_se  mean_ci_lower  mean_ci_upper
0      2020-07-31   2.161468   50.224646     -80.450724      84.773659
1      2020-08-31  10.597280   55.244561     -80.271936     101.466496
2      2020-09-30  19.033093   65.139972     -88.112625     126.178811 }
```

what I would like to achieve is this:

```
    Id       Date    ...  mean_ci_lower  mean_ci_upper
100121 2020-07-31    ...       7.346106     -13.505952
100121 2020-08-31    ...     -13.958985     -13.505952
100140 2020-07-31    ...       7.346106     -13.505952
100140 2020-08-31    ...     -13.958985     -13.505952
```

I am pretty poor with pandas but I feel like i am getting closer but I cannot find the way to deal with the strange headers of the dictionary, I have tried using itertools but without success really.

By the way, this is designed to store more than 1000 `Id`  , can anyone suggest a more efficient way to store predictions results?

UPDATE: as suggested in comment I tried `pd.concat`, while this is closer it eliminate the Id values from the df:

```
      index      mean   mean_se  mean_ci_lower  mean_ci_upper
0 0      2020-07-31 -1.422683  7.346106     -13.505952      10.660585
  1      2020-08-31 -1.875716  7.346106     -13.958985      10.207552
  2      2020-09-30 -2.328749  7.346106     -14.412019       9.754520
      index       mean     mean_se  mean_ci_lower  mean_ci_upper
1 0      2020-07-31   2.161468   50.224646     -80.450724      84.773659
  1      2020-08-31  10.597280   55.244561     -80.271936     101.466496
  2      2020-09-30  19.033093   65.139972     -88.112625     126.178811
```

Comment: Do you need `df = pd.concat(forecast)` ?

Comment: ```pd. concat``` is close but it removes the Id values entirely, let show what it returns in my post

Comment: it returns the same as forecast but at one index. The ids are the names of what is being predicted. so for example for 100121, it will return the 12 predictions rows

Comment: If test my solution what is `print (df.columns.name)` and `print (df.index.name)` ?

Comment: df.columns.name returns the id value and df.index.name returns None. Overall, your solution returns a dataframe with a double index: Id and Date. That's good with me! Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe `id` is `columns.name` or `index.name`:

```
forecast = {}
def holts(i):
    fit1 = ExponentialSmoothing(new_df.iloc[:,i], trend=True).fit()
    prediction_interval = fit1.get_forecast(steps=12).summary_frame(alpha=0.10)

    df = pd.DataFrame(prediction_interval)
    print (df.columns.name)
    print (df.index.name)

    forecast[df.columns.name] = df 
    #or 
    #forecast[df.index.name] = df 
    print(forecast)
    
df = pd.concat(forecast)
```